# Is there earphone ear mold sleeve exists?

Tags: headphones, ear

I am not familiar proper noun in earphone area, I would say

#### earphone sleeve:

[image]

#### earphone ear mold:

[image]

I mean `earphone ear mold sleeve` as a sleeve shape of custom-fit rubber mold.

Because:

1. earphone sleeve: good sound insulation effect, but would feel uncomfortable(or very uncomfortable after some time)
2. customize ear mold is expensive, and limit to some high-end phone. (A cheaper one may be apple's earphone, comfortable but can't isolate outer sound )

I just want to know if such thing exist, what is the name for such stuff?

PS:I think it would be good to customize sleeve mold to fit my ear. I mean the sleeve just looks like the picture 2. And it has a hole like normal ones, then I can plugin any other earphones I like, not limit to some special brand.

Comment: I did a trial week repairing these until the employer decided to keep me and offered 500 euros per month! We're talking soldering under a microscope here. I felt so insulted by how little they offered that I quit the next day.

Answer (score 1):

With in-ear monitors you either get mass produced models with sleeves or you have your ears cast to get a mold and have them custom built.

It is impossible to have mass production prices an something that is custom made as much as it is impossible to for a generic rubber sleeve to fit your ears as well as a custom made mold. I'm afraid there's no in-between (but hopefully I'll be proved wrong as technology progresses).

When you make a mold, the transducer and amp are placed inside the unit and this saves space since everything fits inside your ear (you can see this in the second picture). Sleeves just fit on certain pre-made models.

I think you can 3D scan and 3D print them these days so this could bring prices down.

P.S. Please note that I don't really know the market and I haven't really used them. So there might be solutions out there that I'm not aware of.